# Implicit move functions not being generated

Tags: c++, llvm, c++11

I have the following class:

```
class Blub
{
public:
  Blub(int value); // Not a copy constructor!
  Blub(Blub&&) = default; // This line is necessary because move constructor is not added automatically

  Blub& operator=(Blub&&) = default; // Does not work!?

  // Disallow copy
  Blub(Blub const &) = delete;
  Blub& operator=(Blub const &) = delete;
};
```

For some strange reason I  had to force the move constructor.
Now trying to force the move assignment operator G++ (4.6.1) chokes with: *error: 'Blub& Blub::operator=(Blub&&)' cannot be defaulted*

Sadly there is no WHY. Could anyone shed some light why this is failing

**The Solution:**
Actually I use the dragonegg plugin to generate llvm code. Disabling dragonegg and using normal g++ the defaulting works fine.
Looking at the source of g++ the *cannot be defaulted* (with move assignment) message was a bug in 4.5 (module.c) but got fixed in 4.6.?. Since dragonegg does depend upon g++ 4.5 I suspect that the fix is not in yet. Bummer.

Answer (score 4):

You have to force a move constructor anytime you *explicitly* declare a copy constructor or copy assignment operator, even if you `= default` it, C++11 will not define a move constructor or assignment operator for you. Section 12.8 of the standard (paragraphs 9 and 20) explain the rules for when these are not declared.

As to why the default move constructor doesn't work, I'd guess that it's because `Other` doesn't support move operations.

Comment: I don't default the copy functions - I delete them (there should be a difference ;)).

Comment: @LCID: The standard only allows implicit move constructors/assignment oeprators if the class, "does not have a user-declared copy constructor". In order to delete the copy constructor, you had to _declare_ it. And honestly, if you care about the copy/move behavior enough to explicitly delete the copy constructor, then you care enough to explicitly default the move constructor.

Comment: I'd disagree - but having to explicitly default the functions is ok to me (forces to write some ugly defines - but whatever). The real problem is though - that the move constructor is working/compiling but the move assignment operator is not. And I don't get why.

Comment: @LCID Fire: because the generation of Move Constructors/Assignment for legacy code (written pre-C++0x) should not generate any surprise result. Because experimentations shown that buggy behavior could be introduced in a variety of fashions (and nobody could say what the exact set of conditions was), the Committee took a cautious approach and simply stated that anytime your fiddle with copy/assignment, then no Move Constructor/Assigment would be generated automatically.